# Ember - How to call common validation methods which returns a value

Tags: ember.js

I have a validation method which checks for common validation of values in a input field like empty check, special characters check.

When I call a method using send('methodName'), this will not return a value.

I need to return a value and based on the value I can show messages based on the result.

Code:

Index Template:

```
{{input value=inputval placeholder='Enter Your Name'}}

<div class="submitdiv" {{action 'submitValue'}}>Submit Name</div>
```

App.js:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    inputval: '' 
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function() {
    return ['Jeevi', 'James', 'Tony'];
},
actions: {
submitValue: function(){
    var self = this;
    var temp_val = self.controller.get('inputval');
    var is_valid = self.send('validateName', temp_val); //Need a value returned from this method call
    if( is_valid ){ 
        self.get('controller').model.addObject(temp_val);
    } else {
        alert('Enter a Name');
    }
},
validateName: function(val){  // Need to return a value based on the validation result
    if( val === "" ){ 
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}   
}  
});
```

JSBin Demo [Link](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xipido/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a callback,

**js**

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return ['Jeevi', 'James', 'Tony'];
  },
  actions: {
    submitValue: function(){
      var self = this;
      var temp_val =     self.controller.get('inputval');
      self.send('validateName', temp_val, function(is_valid){
        if( is_valid ){ self.get('controller').model.addObject(temp_val);
     } else {
       alert('Enter a Name');
     }
      });
    },
    validateName: function(val,callback){ 
      if( val === "" ){ 
        callback(false);
      } else {
        callback(true);
      }
    }   
  }  
});
```

http://jsbin.com/ziwosepini/1/edit?html,js

with this approach it is also possible to support ajax/promises, in case a validation needs to be carried out on the server.

http://jsbin.com/cehabojahe/1/edit?html,js